# Different Kotlin versions depending on the flavor

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I want to implement a different Kotlin version to **ONE** specific flavor for an Android Library

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = ...
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


dependencies {
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.32" // will set to 1.4.32
   fooImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72" // ignored
}

// other example
dependencies {
   fooImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72" // ignored, will follow the kotlin-gradle-plugin version (1.4.32)
}
```

Tried with `isForced` and `versions -> strictly("1.3.72")`, but still nothing is working. So the other flavors have to use the older Kotlin version.

Tried this also, but no dice

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        // Special dependency version requested by jd
        if (this.name.toLowerCase().contains("foo")) {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
                
                when (requested.module.toString()){
                    "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib" -> useVersion("1.3.72")
                    "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect" -> useVersion("1.3.72")
                    "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android" -> useVersion("1.3.8")
                }
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it's to prevent the Kotlin Gradle Plugin to add the standard library automatically via a setting in `gradle.properties` according to the documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library

```
// gradle.properties
kotlin.stdlib.default.dependency=false
```